# Unique Key constraint in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

How to set the  Unique Key constraint in Entity Framework  Code First using Configuration or Fluent API.

Comment: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (while they implement the feature Joachim's pointing at), you can create a unique index in a migration.

I would create an "empty" migration and, in the generated class, add the index with [CreateIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829137%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in the Up method and drop it with [DropIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829733%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in the Down method